# Oracle Regex query for specific pattern

Tags: regex, oracle

Could someone help me in framing a regex query which filters the following pattern among different pattern from a column.

pattern: **firstName1 lastName1#firstName2 lastName2**

eg: `George David#William David`

For the below written query, I do get `firstName1 lastName1#firstName2 lastName2` but alongwith `name1#name2` patterns too.

**Query:**

```
select column1 from table where REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '(^|\s|\W)#($|\s|\W)');
```

Comment: The pattern you mentioned is not clear to me: Are you searching for those two names only or for people having last name David? Also, for Regular Expressions, check this page here: https://regex101.com/ it will help you.

Comment: No g00dy. The pattern is actually "firstName1 lastName1#firstName2 lastName2". I just need in that format. "George David#William David" is just an example.

Comment: Try `'^\w+\s+\w+#\w+\s+\w+$'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew ! You' the man ! Thanks a lot ! worked like charm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'(^|\s|\W)#($|\s|\W)'` pattern matches a start of the string, whitespace, or any non-word char, then a `#`, and then the end of string, a whitespace, or any non-word char. You do not restrict the context here and basically just match `#` inside any string not enclosed with word chars.

You need anchors and a more specific pattern:

```
'^\w+\s+\w+#\w+\s+\w+$'
```

You may further adjust it to allow apostrophes or hyphens if necessary by changing `\w+` into something like `\w+([''-]\w+)*` (1+ word chars followed with 0+ sequences of `'` or `-` followed with 1+ word chars).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `#`  - a `#`
- `\w+\s+\w+`  - see above
- `$` - end of string.